# Unity - How do I save .csv files when building an .apk

Tags: c#, android, csv, unity-game-engine

I'm currently storing lists in .csv files, however, when I build the .apk it's like those files never existed at all. How do I manage to save those files in the build so that everything works?

This is the snippet of code I currently have for this situation

```
private static string TODCSVPath = "/Scripts/TOD/TOD_Questions.csv";

public void GenerateTODS() //called in Awake()
    {
        string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.dataPath + TODCSVPath);
        foreach (string uncas in allLines)
        {
            questions.Add(uncas);
        }
    }
```

Everything works dine in the editor and all but I'm really struggling to understand what I need to fix. I searched for a bit and somepeople said to use `string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.persistentDataPath + TODCSVPath);` instead of `string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(Application.dataPath + TODCSVPath);` but that immediately sparks errors in the console.
Also saw something about creating a `TextAsset` and then reading the file from it, but I've not been able to do it at all.

Note: Don't know if this helps but all my .csv files are one column only!

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: suggestion to use Application.persistentDataPath  is a good one. Make sure the path actually exist (create the folders if needed). persistentDataPath will not be in your project folder, check where it is by printing debug

Comment: Only files in Resource folders are part of the build. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple options:

1- **Resources**

Unity includes assets under [Resources folders](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) in player builds. Simply put your .csv file under Assets/Resources/ folder. Then you can access it like this:

```cs
TextAsset myTextAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("myfile"); // omit file extension
string csvText = myTextAsset.text;
...
```

2- **Reference as a Text Asset**

You can also link a .csv file as a text file from a MonoBehaviour in a scene or resource that goes into the build. That is how materials and other assets go into player builds.

For example if you have this component on a GameObject in a build scene, you can access the TextAsset. Technically the "file" is not included in the player build, because Unity packs the assets. But you have access to the CSV content.

```cs
public class MyMono : MonoBehaviour {
  [SerializeField] TextAsset _textAsset;

  void Start() {
    string csvText = _textAsset.text;
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In my humble opinion, it appears  `Resource.Load < TextAsset > ( 'fileNameOnly' )` is the way to go, instead of 'fileNameWithExtension' as a parameter to `Load` function call. Rest of the information is good :-)